# how to recive url after upload to youtube and how to search by developer tag (version v3)

Tags: android, youtube-api, google-api-java-client, android-youtube-api

my app upload video to youtube, i need after the upload to recive url and search by developer tag.

i'm use this way https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert to upload videos.

i saw this link to show how to do this but in version 2.0, i'm use v3

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_uploading_videos#Assigning_Developer_Tags

```
<media:category
  scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/developertags.cat">TagName
</media:category>
```

in the documentation of v3 i do not find "developer tag"
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started

i need simple explanation how to attach developer tag to upload and how to receive url after the upload

thanks ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In url you added  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert  there is a section called "Response". In there you can read that after insert you get VideoResource:

```
        {
      "id": string,
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": etag,
      "snippet": {
       ... ( and more... )
```

Key "id" contains id to your video. Your video can be found here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={VIDEO_ID}